# Did a cop get fired after stopping police abuse?

Tags: united-states, police

From https://twitter.com/PolicePoliceACP/status/546020531665772544 (1754 retweets, 705 favorites)

> Cop Stops Cop From Choking a Handcuffed Man, She Was Then Beaten/Fired
>
> Read more >> [http://bit.ly/1DQqUAT](http://thefreethoughtproject.com/police-departments-good-cops-buffalo-officer-fired-stopping-brutality/) #PolTwt

[image: Text below]

> This cop [Officer Carol Horne] tried to stop this cop [Officer Gregory
>   Kwiatkowski] from beating and choking a handcuffed suspect.
>
> She was then beaten & fired.
>
> She says: "I don't regret it, I'd do it again".
>
> And is now fighting to keep her pension after 19 years on the force.
>
> SHARE if you wish more cops had integrity like this woman

Is preventing police abuse an accurate and complete description of Horne's actions, and was she fired soon afterwards and denied her pension?

Answer (score 28):

Cariol Horne says she intervened in the other officer's interaction with a suspect. 
She was fired. She was been denied pension, as she was fired before the date at which it would be awarded. [Source: WIVB TV: Council won’t restore officer’s pension](http://wivb.com/2014/12/09/fired-police-officer-may-get-pension-back/)

I can't find anything showing she was beaten.

Her claim is that the other officer punched her and was unnecessarily punching and choking the suspect.  [Source: Counter Current News: New York Cop Was Fired and Denied Pension For Trying To Stop Fellow Officer From Choking Suspect](http://countercurrentnews.com/2014/12/new-york-cop-was-fired-and-denied-pension-for-trying-to-stop-fellow-officer-from-choking-suspect/#)

The other officer, Greg Kwiatkowski, says that Cariol was the aggressor against him. [Source: Political Affairs: Embattled White Police Officer Lashes out at Horne](http://www.politicalaffairs.net/embattled-white-police-officer-lashes-out-at-horne/)
 (I don't think this difference between their stories was ever resolved.)

Kwiatkowski sued Cariol for defamation relating to her description of this event and won: [Source: WGRZ TV: Police Lieutenant Vindicated](http://archive.wgrz.com/news/article/109161/13/Police-Lieutenant-Vindicated?fullsite=true)

Comment: She claims she was punched hard enough to require her bridge to be replaced. Also, [this article](http://www.wkbw.com/news/fired-buffalo-cop-id-do-it-again) has additional information about Kwiatkowski:

"Officer Kwiatkowski was forced to retire from the police department after he was suspended for choking another officer on the job, and in a separate incident, punching another officer when he was off the clock.

In May 2014, Kwiatowkski and two other officers were indicted on federal civil rights violations against black teen suspects."

Comment: The WGRZ link no longer works and was excluded from the Wayback Machine.